# Chat room compatibility for iPhone

Tags: support, chat

I am logged into the forums through my iPhone but when I try to enter the chat rooms, it says I must log in. When I enter my credentials it says it cannot find my account, then asks if I would like to make a new SE account from this information. Is this a common issue and if so is there a work around?

I am using an old iPhone 4 with most current iOS(7.1.1)